# WD Smartware or Equivalent

Tags: 16.04, backup, external-hdd

Recently I changed my operating system to Ubuntu 16.04. Before I had Windows 10 and used Western Digital SmartWare to make backups on an external drive from my WD hard drive. Now Ubuntu recognizes the external drive but intended to do backups with some software instead of manually transfer to the external drive. Is there any Ubuntu application to replace  WD SmartWare? Thank you.

Comment: Please write your question in English.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu has a built-in utility to do this!

Simply search for "Backups" in the dash, and the app will pop up:
[image]

Click on the icon to open it, and then you should see this:
[image]

Simply adjust the settings to your liking, and do a backup.